# what's the meaning of "|=" in PHP

Tags: php

I'm reading other's php code, and there's one line writes:

```
    if ($isprivate)
  {
    $status |= STATUS_PRIVATE;
  }
```

I have no idea what does "|=" mean?
Can anyone help on it?

Comment: Bitwise "or" shorthand.

Comment: Did you try looking for a list of operators in official PHP documentation?

Comment: Any operator of the form `a ⊛= b` is a shorthand for `a = a ⊛ b`

Comment: In general, any binary operator can be used in the form `dest <op>= expression`, it means `dest = dest <op> expression`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

| is a bitwise operator. It takes two numbers and conducts a bitwise OR operation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_OR#OR

Ex:
A = 4
B = 3

In binary:
A = 100
B = 011

A | B == 111 (in binary) == 7 (in decimal)

A |= B is the same as A = A | B

In your specific example, the code is checking to see if $isPrivate is true. If it is, it makes the bit marked by STATUS_PRIVATE set to TRUE in the $status variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorthand of this:

```
$status =  $status | STATUS_PRIVATE;
```

[Or (inclusive or)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

For example

```
define(STATUS_PRIVATE, 0b01);
$status = 0b00;
$status |= STATUS_PRIVATE; //status become 0b01;
```

Comment: This is doing what exactly?

Comment: It sets the `STATUS_PRIVATE` flag to true.